# Winston is not properly working, I am unable to get all the console values in log file using winston

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, winston

I want to store all the **console** values in **log file** using Winstone, but I have ended up to store only the morgan values and not the console.log values in my log file.

**And I also want to store the error values in my error.log file which I am unable to get it right now. Here below is my code.**

> winston.js file

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
  file: {
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  errorFile: {
   level: 'error',
   name: 'file.error',
   filename: `${appRoot}/logs/error.log`,
   handleExceptions: true,
   json: true,
   maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
   maxFiles: 100,
   colorize: true,
 },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
var logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.File(options.errorFile),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// create a stream object with a 'write' function that will be used by `morgan`
logger.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding) {
    logger.info(message);
  },
};

module.exports = logger;
```

> main.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const morgon=require("morgan");


var winston = require('./config/winston');
app.use(morgon("combined", { stream: winston.stream }));
```